# NgIf does not work with undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

I want to display message with usage of ngIf:

```
<div *ngIf="airplaneType === undefined" class="error">
     Choose correct airplane from the list!
 </div>
```

It seems very strange, because it does not work although after each change on the select list, I am logging in the console:

```
console.log(this.airplaneType === undefined);
```

and it returns true.

I am using the Angular 4.4.4.

Comment: please use == instead of === and use single quote for 'undefined'

Comment: it works as expected. What is the data-type of `airplaneType`?

Comment: I tried with == and it has not helped.

Comment: @Faisal it is my custom model, it consists of several strings.

Comment: It would be simpler to just use `*ngIf="!airplaneType"`, but if you want help, post a complete minimal example, as a plnkr, reproducing the problem.

Comment: !airplaneType and comparing to null also does not work

Comment: Are you initializing the model in your code? If yes, then the behavior is correct. Here is a working example:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-beta-12-i9bwd2?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I came to solution. I  have in the form in other place the control with such a name, therefore the conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to a solution. I had in the form the control with such a name. Because of that there was the conflict

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
<div [class.error]="airplaneType === undefined">
     Choose correct airplane from the list!
</div>
```